# PowerShell - Search pattern from particular lines

Tags: powershell

I wrote below command to search all files within Workflow folders and look for only those files that matched pattern 'TextBox.TextBox'. It worked fine.

Now I want to change the command so it only search pattern from line 1 till line 50, instead to search whole file. How can I do that ?

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Test\Workflow -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "TextBox.TextBox" -SimpleMatch | group path 
| select name | measure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet to filter all matches with `LineNumber` less equal 50:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Test\Workflow -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "TextBox.TextBox" -SimpleMatch | Where-Object LineNumber -le 50 group path
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Get-Content` and `Select-Object -First`:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Test\Workflow -Recurse |ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content -Path $_.FullName |Select-Object -First 50
} |Select-String -Pattern "TextBox.TextBox" -SimpleMatch
```

Comment: @user664481 You are of course welcome to mark whichever answer you want as accepted but I would consider marking the answer which best answers your question as supposed to which came in first. Depending on how big your file is this might be better anyway as if won't read in the entire file in order to do the search.